# Can a miner compromise an EVM that runs a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, security, evm

For example, there is a private storage variable which cannot be seen by any user during the execution of the smart contract.

When a miner runs the smart contract in a local EVM, can it infer the value of the private variable by, for example, monitoring the memory?

(Suppose the miner machine is completely malicious, including the kernel and the user space.)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example, there is a private storage variable which cannot be seen by any user during the execution of the smart contract.

It's not possible to have any kind of 'private' data on a public blockchain. All data is visible to all fully synchronized nodes in the network.

Comment: I know you can see all the transactions that happened with a particular address and trace through inputs to determine the value of private vars, but do you know any other ways to see the value of private vars? Could you look in the state tree directly or something similar?